# In `find -exec`, using back quotes (backticks) with `stat`

Tags: find, stat

I would like `find` to execute a different command depending on what the `stat`s of a file are.

If I run the command

```
find . -name "*" -exec echo {} \+
```

then I get the list of files in the directory.  As expected, adding echo `` gives the same result:

```
find . -name "*" -exec echo `echo {}` \+
```

On the other hand, with `stat` the situation is different.

```
find . -name "*" -exec stat {} \+
```

works as expected.  However,

```
find . -name "*" -exec echo `stat {}` \+
```

returns the error

```
stat: {}: stat: No such file or directory
```

In this case, the braces `{}` do not get expanded like they do in the `echo` example.  How do I make the expansion work as expected?

Comment: It *is* working as expected, surely? in the first case, `echo {}` is executed inside the command substitution, outputting literal `{}`, so the arguments to the find command become `-exec {} +` - whereas the execution of `stat {}` inside the command substitution produces an error. What is your end goal here?

Comment: You can't. The 'expansion' of `{}` to a found filename is done by `find` _after_ it has found a suitable file and it exec's the program and argument(s) you specify. Process substitution with backticks or the newer/better `$( ... )` syntax is done by the shell before even starting `find`, so none of the (possibly many) filenames that will be found in the future is yet known. You need to be a Time Lord (or companion) or god to go backward in time and make this work.; we would be interested to hear when you achieve either of those.

Comment: @steeldriver The end goal is to execute a different command depending on the `stat` output, I edited the question to specify this.

Comment: in that case you probably want a construct like `-exec sh -c 'for f; do stuff with "$f"; done' find-sh {} +` (unless the `stat` test you want to apply can be achieved via one of find's built-in tests like `-size`, `-perm` etc.)